# OSM Overpy Geometries

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, shapely

I want to return a Geo data frame for OSM data using Overpy. This is easy to do with overpass and shapely using the verbosity = 'geom' in the api.get statement but overpass does not allow you to work with relations (to my knowledge)

So I am working with overpy with the following query:

```
import overpy
import requests
import json
import geojson

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="IS"][admin_level=2];
(
 way["natural"="glacier"](area);
 rel["natural"="glacier"](area);
);
out geom;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url, 
                        params={'data': overpass_query})
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()
```

This returns a dict (snippet pasted below) ... and I would like to convert it to a geodataframe or geojson format:

```
 {'version': 0.6,
 'generator': 'Overpass API 0.7.56.8 7d656e78',
 'osm3s': {'timestamp_osm_base': '2021-02-15T15:22:03Z',
  'timestamp_areas_base': '2021-02-15T15:11:02Z',
  'copyright': 'The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.'},
 'elements': [{'type': 'way',
   'id': 25572229,
   'bounds': {'minlat': 64.7317767,
    'minlon': -19.7595973,
    'maxlat': 64.7600927,
    'maxlon': -19.6928364},
   'nodes': [278755095,
    4988895563,
    4988895561,
    4988895562,
    278755096,
    4988895559,
    278755097,
    4988895560,
    4988895557,
    4988895558,
    4988895556,
    278755098,
    4988895555,
    4988895554,
    4988895553,
    278755099,
    278755100,
    278755101,
    278755102,
    278755103,
    5986523217,
    5986523216,
    278755104,
    278755105,
    5986523215,
    5986523214,
    5986523212,
    5986523213,
    278755106,
    278755107,
    278755108,
    278755109,
    278755110,
    278755111,
    278755112,
    278755113,
    278755114,
    278755115,
    278755116,
    278755117,
    278755118,
    278755119,
    278755120,
    278755124,
    278755125,
    278755126,
    278755130,
    278755131,
    278755132,
    278755133,
    278755134,
    278755135,
    278755136,
    278755137,
    4988895564,
    4988895566,
    4988895565,
    4988895568,
    4988895567,
    4988895569,
    278755095],
   'geometry': [{'lat': 64.7332811, 'lon': -19.7278524},
    {'lat': 64.7329093, 'lon': -19.7341986},
    {'lat': 64.7334309, 'lon': -19.7383334},
    {'lat': 64.7342309, 'lon': -19.7400297},
    {'lat': 64.7345084, 'lon': -19.7429107},
    {'lat': 64.7358988, 'lon': -19.7458491},
    {'lat': 64.7356206, 'lon': -19.7496168},
    {'lat': 64.7360086, 'lon': -19.7512644},
    {'lat': 64.7357056, 'lon': -19.7537414},
    {'lat': 64.7381456, 'lon': -19.7541846},
    {'lat': 64.7385295, 'lon': -19.7531667},
    {'lat': 64.7394417, 'lon': -19.7538338},
    {'lat': 64.7407874, 'lon': -19.7544468},
    {'lat': 64.741594, 'lon': -19.7539147},
    {'lat': 64.7429881, 'lon': -19.7545682},
    {'lat': 64.744698, 'lon': -19.7551248},
    {'lat': 64.7508682, 'lon': -19.7575374},
    {'lat': 64.7555541, 'lon': -19.7595973},
    {'lat': 64.7598548, 'lon': -19.7564644},
    {'lat': 64.7600927, 'lon': -19.7548981},
    {'lat': 64.7583663, 'lon': -19.7500575},
    {'lat': 64.7597724, 'lon': -19.7487397},
    {'lat': 64.7573843, 'lon': -19.7443194},
    {'lat': 64.7569176, 'lon': -19.7436757},
    {'lat': 64.7538784, 'lon': -19.7439045},
    {'lat': 64.7508483, 'lon': -19.737696},
    {'lat': 64.7489433, 'lon': -19.7360508},
    {'lat': 64.7488348, 'lon': -19.7349065},
    {'lat': 64.7502824, 'lon': -19.7324748},
    {'lat': 64.7551148, 'lon': -19.724235},
    {'lat': 64.7589216, 'lon': -19.7129054},
    {'lat': 64.7568718, 'lon': -19.7125621},
    {'lat': 64.7518933, 'lon': -19.7225184},
    {'lat': 64.7489644, 'lon': -19.7218318},
    {'lat': 64.7470604, 'lon': -19.7232051},
    {'lat': 64.7448633, 'lon': -19.7225184},
    {'lat': 64.7488179, 'lon': -19.7170253},
    {'lat': 64.7521862, 'lon': -19.7129054},
    {'lat': 64.7545291, 'lon': -19.7074122},
    {'lat': 64.752772, 'lon': -19.7022624},
    {'lat': 64.7468923, 'lon': -19.7110574},
    {'lat': 64.7471989, 'lon': -19.7043811},
    {'lat': 64.746467, 'lon': -19.7010805},
    {'lat': 64.7449527, 'lon': -19.7017042},
    {'lat': 64.7428125, 'lon': -19.7032924},
    {'lat': 64.7410546, 'lon': -19.7101588},
    {'lat': 64.7377485, 'lon': -19.7079655},
    {'lat': 64.7356578, 'lon': -19.6992603},
    {'lat': 64.7362158, 'lon': -19.694227},
    {'lat': 64.7356134, 'lon': -19.6928364},
    {'lat': 64.7351069, 'lon': -19.6939175},
    {'lat': 64.7337628, 'lon': -19.6957344},
    {'lat': 64.7317767, 'lon': -19.6957953},
    {'lat': 64.7329861, 'lon': -19.703479},
    {'lat': 64.736968, 'lon': -19.7112033},
    {'lat': 64.7357176, 'lon': -19.7191862},
    {'lat': 64.7358998, 'lon': -19.7209692},
    {'lat': 64.7344614, 'lon': -19.7209821},
    {'lat': 64.7335286, 'lon': -19.7222981},
    {'lat': 64.732916, 'lon': -19.7276224},
    {'lat': 64.7332811, 'lon': -19.7278524}],
   'tags': {'alt_name': 'Regnbúðajökull',
    'name': 'Hrútfellsjökull',
    'natural': 'glacier'}},
  {'type': 'way',
   'id': 250745561,
   'bounds': {'minlat': 64.7129996,
    'minlon': -17.9851867,
    'maxlat': 64.7859787,
    'maxlon': -17.8182245},
   'nodes': [8117616831,
    8117616832,
    8117616833,
    8117616834,
    8117616835,
    8117616836,
    8117616837,
    8117616838,
    8117616839,
    8117616840,
    8117616841,
    8117616842,
    8117616843,
    8117616844,
    8117616845,
    8117616846,
    8117616847,
    8117616848,
    8117616849,
    8117616850,
    8117616851,
    8117616852,
    8117616853,
    8117616854,
    8117616855,
    8117616856,
    8117616857,
    8117616858,
    8117616859,
    8117616860,
    8117616861,
    8117616862,
    8117616863,
    8117616864,
    8117616865,
    8117616866,
    8117616867,
    8117616868,
    8117616869,
    8117616870,
    8117616871,
    8117616872,
    8117616873,
    8117616874,
    8117616875,
    8117616876,
    2571248283,
    2571248282,
    2571248279,
    2571248278,
    2571248280,
    2571248277,
    2571248275,
    2571248273,
    2571248272,
    2571248271,
    2571248270,
    2571248268,
    2571248263,
    2571248254,
    2571248250,
    2571248248,
    2571248249,
    2571248252,
    2571248253,
    2571248251,
    2571248246,
    2571248244,
    2571248241,
    2571248240,
    2571248242,
    2571248243,
    2571248245,
    2571248247,
    2571248261,
    2571248265,
    2571248269,
    2571248274,
    2571248276,
    2571248281,
    2571248284,
    2571248285,
    2571248287,
    2571248291,
    2571248292,
    2571248293,
    2571248295,
    2571248296,
    2571248298,
    2571248300,
    2571248304,
    2571248302,
    2571248299,
    2571248301,
    2571248305,
    2571248308,
    2571248316,
    2571248313,
    3682713435,
    2571248309,
    2571248307,
    2571248315,
    2571248322,
    2571248323,
    2571248324,
    3682713436,
    2571248325,
    2571248327,
    2571248328,
    2571248330,
    2571248332,
    2571248333,
    2571248335,
    2571248336,
    2571248338,
    2571248342,
    2571248345,
    2571248347,
    2571248350,
    2571248352,
    2571248361,
    2571248365,
    2571248354,
    2571248351,
    2571248353,
    2571248362,
    2571248369,
    2571248372,
    2571248376,
    2571248379,
    308853335,
    308853337,
    308853338,
    2571248363,
    2571248355,
    2571248358,
    2571248367,
    2571248366,
    2571248359,
    2571248349,
    2571248344,
    2571248340,
    2571248339,
    2571248346,
    2571248364,
    2571248374,
    2571248378,
    308853340,
    308853342,
    2571248389,
    308853344,
    308853346,
    2571248388,
    308853347,
    308853349,
    308853351,
    308853353,
    308853355,
    308853357,
    2571248384,
    2571248382,
    2571248380,
    2571248370,
    2571248360,
    2571248357,
    2571248371,
    2571248375,
    2571248381,
    2571248385,
    2571248387,
    2571248386,
    2571248383,
    2571248377,
    2571248373,
    2571248368,
    2571248356,
    2571248348,
    2571248343,
    2571248341,
    2571248337,
    2571248334,
    2571248331,
    2571248329,
    2571248326,
    2571248319,
    2571248318,
    2571248312,
    2571248311,
    2571248317,
    2571248321,
    2571248320,
    2571248314,
    2571248310,
    2571248306,
    2571248303,
    2571248297,
    2571248294,
    8117616831],
   'geometry': [{'lat': 64.7401232, 'lon': -17.8838301},
    {'lat': 64.7392308, 'lon': -17.8813838},
    {'lat': 64.7386814, 'lon': -17.8779721},
    {'lat': 64.738425, 'lon': -17.8746032},
    {'lat': 64.7377931, 'lon': -17.8736591},
    {'lat': 64.7368224, 'lon': -17.8739595},
    {'lat': 64.7361997, 'lon': -17.8749251},
    {'lat': 64.7355678, 'lon': -17.8799462},
    {'lat': 64.7360074, 'lon': -17.8840875},
    {'lat': 64.7357784, 'lon': -17.8851818},
    {'lat': 64.7353846, 'lon': -17.8852677},
    {'lat': 64.734771, 'lon': -17.8850745},
    {'lat': 64.7344047, 'lon': -17.8851818},
    {'lat': 64.7343131, 'lon': -17.8857827},
    {'lat': 64.7343314, 'lon': -17.8867697},
    {'lat': 64.7345329, 'lon': -17.8877997},
    {'lat': 64.7350183, 'lon': -17.8887438},
    {'lat': 64.7350549, 'lon': -17.8896236},
    {'lat': 64.7348993, 'lon': -17.8906321},
    {'lat': 64.7349725, 'lon': -17.892456},
    {'lat': 64.7348993, 'lon': -17.8928422},
    {'lat': 64.7341025, 'lon': -17.893486},
    {'lat': 64.7340842, 'lon': -17.8941726},
    {'lat': 64.7343955, 'lon': -17.89649},
    {'lat': 64.7349084, 'lon': -17.8969192},
    {'lat': 64.7352289, 'lon': -17.8966188},
    {'lat': 64.7349908, 'lon': -17.8953099},
    {'lat': 64.7350641, 'lon': -17.8950309},
    {'lat': 64.7352289, 'lon': -17.8949022},
    {'lat': 64.7353846, 'lon': -17.8948807},
    {'lat': 64.7354487, 'lon': -17.8945374},
    {'lat': 64.7355312, 'lon': -17.8946018},
    {'lat': 64.735577, 'lon': -17.8952455},
    {'lat': 64.7357326, 'lon': -17.8955888},
    {'lat': 64.735696, 'lon': -17.8958678},
    {'lat': 64.7355037, 'lon': -17.8957176},
    {'lat': 64.7353388, 'lon': -17.89649},
    {'lat': 64.735348, 'lon': -17.8981423},
    {'lat': 64.7351465, 'lon': -17.8990435},
    {'lat': 64.735174, 'lon': -17.900288},
    {'lat': 64.7349084, 'lon': -17.9009318},
    {'lat': 64.7346245, 'lon': -17.902348},
    {'lat': 64.7347069, 'lon': -17.9035925},
    {'lat': 64.7350458, 'lon': -17.9045796},
    {'lat': 64.7350916, 'lon': -17.9063176},
    {'lat': 64.7344597, 'lon': -17.9077124},
    {'lat': 64.733053, 'lon': -17.910492},
    {'lat': 64.7322122, 'lon': -17.9145087},
    {'lat': 64.731355, 'lon': -17.9174054},
    {'lat': 64.7312725, 'lon': -17.9140839},
    {'lat': 64.7314868, 'lon': -17.9094879},
    {'lat': 64.7302998, 'lon': -17.9078271},
    {'lat': 64.7291622, 'lon': -17.9114962},
    {'lat': 64.7272331, 'lon': -17.9150494},
    {'lat': 64.7270517, 'lon': -17.9189116},
    {'lat': 64.7265405, 'lon': -17.9256704},
    {'lat': 64.7261613, 'lon': -17.9287216},
    {'lat': 64.7253533, 'lon': -17.9327382},
    {'lat': 64.7232095, 'lon': -17.9360983},
    {'lat': 64.7215109, 'lon': -17.9417371},
    {'lat': 64.7207192, 'lon': -17.9475304},
    {'lat': 64.720241, 'lon': -17.9532078},
    {'lat': 64.7206698, 'lon': -17.9567996},
    {'lat': 64.7213625, 'lon': -17.9596963},
    {'lat': 64.7214284, 'lon': -17.9635198},
    {'lat': 64.7207522, 'lon': -17.9679227},
    {'lat': 64.7195482, 'lon': -17.9693903},
    {'lat': 64.7163648, 'lon': -17.9710511},
    {'lat': 64.7138244, 'lon': -17.9694676},
    {'lat': 64.7129996, 'lon': -17.969931},
    {'lat': 64.7145668, 'lon': -17.9714759},
    {'lat': 64.7163483, 'lon': -17.9731753},
    {'lat': 64.7185751, 'lon': -17.9742567},
    {'lat': 64.7201255, 'lon': -17.9746815},
    {'lat': 64.722319, 'lon': -17.9763036},
    {'lat': 64.7243309, 'lon': -17.9801272},
    {'lat': 64.7257985, 'lon': -17.9799341},
    {'lat': 64.7284532, 'lon': -17.9794706},
    {'lat': 64.7299701, 'lon': -17.9799341},
    {'lat': 64.7316022, 'lon': -17.9786982},
    {'lat': 64.7339267, 'lon': -17.9808224},
    {'lat': 64.7354762, 'lon': -17.9829466},
    {'lat': 64.7364322, 'lon': -17.9823287},
    {'lat': 64.7375201, 'lon': -17.9840666},
    {'lat': 64.7392672, 'lon': -17.9839894},
    {'lat': 64.7401077, 'lon': -17.9789686},
    {'lat': 64.7416569, 'lon': -17.9761878},
    {'lat': 64.7428764, 'lon': -17.9747588},
    {'lat': 64.7454141, 'lon': -17.9707807},
    {'lat': 64.7466499, 'lon': -17.9663392},
    {'lat': 64.7482316, 'lon': -17.9666482},
    {'lat': 64.7476055, 'lon': -17.9703945},
    {'lat': 64.7462544, 'lon': -17.9758402},
    {'lat': 64.7466499, 'lon': -17.9805134},
    {'lat': 64.7487259, 'lon': -17.984028},
    {'lat': 64.7518066, 'lon': -17.9851867},
    {'lat': 64.7542282, 'lon': -17.9786982},
    {'lat': 64.7537669, 'lon': -17.9734843},
    {'lat': 64.7535401, 'lon': -17.9713788},
    {'lat': 64.7519878, 'lon': -17.9696221},
```

Comment: Documentation found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670206/how-do-i-get-the-geometry-of-a-relation-from-openstreetmap

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but you can do this by using `osm2geojson` like this:

```py
import osm2geojson    

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': request})
if response.status_code == 200:
    # convert result to GeoDataFrame
    data = response.json()
    geojson = osm2geojson.json2geojson(data)
    geojsonDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all the elements returned are polygons (which seems to be the case in your example), you can write a function converting each element returned by the overpass API into a GeoJSON Feature in order to collect all these features in a list.
Then it is easy to create a GeoDataFrame for this list of features :

```
import geopandas as gpd

def elem_to_feature(elem):
    return {
        "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[[d["lon"], d["lat"]] for d in elem["geometry"]]]
        },
        "properties": elem["tags"],
    }


# the 'data' variable is from the code in the question
features = [elem_to_feature(elem) for elem in data["elements"]]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(features)
```

Comment: That works well for the OSM 'ways' but 'relations' are multi-polygons and I am having a hard time re-working that into useable geometry